# Mockito: capturing HttpServletResponse#sendError()

Tags: java, servlets, mockito

Can I use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to capture what was passed to the `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` method? I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the verify method on Mockito to do this. Usually mocking HttpResponse isn't a pleasant experience though.

```
mockResponse = mock(HttpSR→);
//…
verify(mockResponse, times(1)).sendError(..);
```

As arguments to `sendError` you can then pass mockito matchers, which can do any check on the argument that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I think the poster wanted to know, how to retrieve the arguments that were passed to the method. You can use:

```
// given
HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class); 
ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
ArgumentCaptor<String> stringArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
doNothing().when(response).sendError(intArg.capture(), stringArg.capture());

// when (do your test here)
response.sendError(404, "Not found");

// then (do your assertions here, I just print out the values)
System.out.println(intArg.getValue());
System.err.println(stringArg.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Mockito spies](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) (chapter 13). For objects you can't mock, you can sometimes examine their internals and stub certain methods this way.

If you can post some sample code, I can take a look at it.

Comment: In this case I don't have a real object.  I'm doing:  mock(HttpServletResponse.class).  In the code it calls the sendError() method.  Maybe I just need to create my own mock implementation fo HttpServletResponse.  I was hoping Mockito had a was to save any time sendError() was called so I could retrieve the results later on.

Comment: Looking at the Spy docs showed me how simple this is:

        verify(res).sendError(404);

Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I have been wrestling with Mockito myself lately. It's amazing, except when it isn't.